# cant login into paypal sandbox site (paypal hell)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to login to my sandbox account (using chrome)  but since the new change in paypal i cant.
PayPal now ask me to log in to the developer site. i do.
and then i go to the applications->sandbox accounts and there press the 'sanbox site' link.
if am lucky then i then get the login screen to the sandbox.
i enter my credentials and click on the login button.
i then get this screen:
[image]

I press the "paypal sandbox" link and i return again to the developer.paypal.com site.
ofcurse i use the email address that is listed in my sandbox account.

if i try and use firefox and go to developer.paypal.com i get a very long json response
that start like this

```
{"data":{"master":"inc/master","googleAnalyticAccountId":
```

ok i am not giving up i go and delete all my cookies that belong to paypal i then go to 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/home now i enter my credentials again now i get this screen:

[image]

i click the "paypal sandbox" link and i get the long json again :(
another wonderful work by paypal.

btw i contacted paypal on the 8/5/13 but did not get an answer yet.

does anyone know of way to end this hell and be able to use my sandbox again ?

Comment: Are you using the email that you initially created your account with or the email you are using for test accounts ?

Comment: i am using the my test account email.the "Email ID" in the profile data of the sandbox account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing all of your cookies and cache prior to opening up your browser window.  The once you have done this, open up a browser.  Pull up a tab, and navigate to developer.paypal.com and log in.  Once you have successfully logged in, you should be able to test your site, or the sandbox site.  Open up your site or the sandbox site in a different tab while leaving the developer.com site up.